# How do I call a function to change a value in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need something like this, but it doesn't work

```
.directive('dateTime', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope:'=value',
            template: "<div>{{value.format('mmm dd yy')}}"</div>", 
                                    // ^here: applying a function to the scope  
         };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created an isolate scope with `scope: '=value'` so this is a brand new scope that does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope.  This means that any functions you want to call must be from

1. a service, filter, etc. you injected into the directive
2. another directive's controller, use `require` to get access (see the `tabs` and `pane` directives on the Angular home page for an example)
3. a function you define in the directive's controller or in the link function on $scope (which are essentially the same thing)  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621193/215945
4. use the '&' syntax to enable the directive to call a function declared on the parent scope.  Example: [What is the best way to implement a button that needs to be disabled while submitting in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493050/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-button-that-needs-to-be-disabled-while-submi/14494122#14494122)

Answer (score 0):

You might just be looking for the [date filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate):

```
{{value | date:'MMM dd yy'}}
```

but you can do this too:

```
app.directive('dateTime', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope:'=value',
            template: "<div>{{value | date:'MMM dd yy')}}"</div>", 
                                    // ^here: applying a function to the scope  
         };
    });
```

Comment: well it's not the same... value can be not exactly date time format, I need to apply a function, any arbitrary function to it

Comment: so you need to call a scope function from the directive?

Comment: I have a directive, in its template I use another directive that suppose to call some arbitrary function and apply it to the value